# ansible / boto / any other suggestions - update ASG tag

Tags: tags, ansible, autoscaling

Would anyone have suggestions, pointers, examples of updating a current ASG's tagging?

I have a need to update tags on ASGs rather frequently.  So far, playing with ec2_asg, I'm unable to figure out if it's possible.  My next best so far has been having ansible run the CLI commands themselves.  Before I start going the boto path and writing my own script, I thought I'd ask the community.

Any suggestion, pointer or example is always appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ec2_tag module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_tag_module.html). Just apply the tags you want on the ASG ARN.

> Creates, removes and lists tags from any EC2 resource. The resource is referenced by its resource id (e.g. an instance being `i-XXXXXXX`). It is designed to be used with complex args (tags), see the examples. This module has a dependency on python-boto.

Comment: So i've been playing with this for a few weeks (off and on as work allows), any chance you can provide an example? I was hoping to do this without having to supply the ARN manually.